# Mouse right-click is not working anymore when using ArcGIS10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, editing

The mouse right-click option has stopped working with ArcGIS10. It happened suddenly - the mouse is ok (not broken) as it works with other programs. Do you know what happened and how to fix it?

The right-click option is useful for editing as you can just right-click select from the drop down list, absolute coordinates, direction, delete sketch etc. It is also not working, when I'm in layout view as I can't change grid properties.

Comment: Not really an answer, but have you tried restarting your computer? I've had odd problems in the past with ArcGIS which have gone away after restarting windows.

Comment: Is the right-click broken in all circumstances, or just when editing? Eg, can you right-click on a layer's name in the Table of Contents, or the data frame itself, or a legend object (scalebar, etc)? This will help to decide where the problem lies

Comment: I wonder if you have an extension installed that [subclasses](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/Windows_subclassing.aspx) the activeview's window and is catching the WM_ right click message without forwarding it.

Comment: It can be an extension issue in ArcGIS - PLTS (now called ESRI Production Mapping ) can effect the mouse functions.

Comment: Although this was over a year ago have you found the solution? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I had this problem when I was editing with a topology.  I had validated the topology and the dialog box that popped up at the end of the validation was hidden in the background and the right click started working again when I closed the dialog box.

Comment: I have that same problem, my right mouse button stop working.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to rename your Normal.mxt file located here and re-boot.

C:\Users\wsmith\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.4\ArcMap\Templates

Comment: you do not need to reboot just exit arcmap and re launch it.